# XMPPFramework server feature

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I'm trying to get server feature and XMPP configuration is:

```
 _xmppCapabilitiesStorage = [XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
_xmppCapabilities = [[XMPPCapabilities alloc] initWithCapabilitiesStorage:_xmppCapabilitiesStorage];
_xmppCapabilities.autoFetchMyServerCapabilities = YES;
```

the log says:

```
SEND: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<iq type="get" to="myserver.im" id="4FE37B35-8078-41B0-BCAF-DC6CFF04DD33">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
</iq>
```

RECV:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="4FE37B35-8078-41B0-BCAF-DC6CFF04DD33" from="myserver.im" to="3471@myserver.im/MyChatClient">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
        <identity category="account" type="registered"/>
        <identity category="pubsub" type="pep"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"/>
        <feature var="urn:myserver:im:groupchat#sync"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"/>
        <feature var="vcard-temp"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"/>
        <feature var="urn:myserver:im:groupchat"/>
        <feature var="urn:xmpp:ping"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:register"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"/>
        <feature var="urn:myserver:im:filetransfer"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#auto-create"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:roster"/>
        <feature var="urn:xmpp:mam:1"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#access-open"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:version"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"/>
        <feature var="urn:xmpp:time"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:privacy"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:last"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/offline"/>
        <feature var="urn:xmpp:carbons:2"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/address"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
        <feature var="jabber:iq:private"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

how to check later on which feature does exist? I don't see any feature list in the `XMPPCapabilities` or `XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage`. Am I missing something? For example, I want to check whether `<feature var="urn:myserver:im:filetransfer"/>` does exist. Where does XMPPFramework save and hold list of features? any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: I think this link useful: http://jonathonstaff.com/blog/tackling-file-transfers-with-the-xmppframework/

Comment: @Jay thanks, I checked already, but that didn't say where XMPPFramework holds list of the features. I'm debugging the framework to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have found out where the information are stored:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage sharedInstance] mainThreadManagedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"XMPPCapsResourceCoreDataStorageObject"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30;
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"jidStr == %@", _domain];
fetchRequest.predicate = filter;
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *features = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSArray *ch = [[[[features firstObject] caps] capabilities] children];
```